# MySQL/PHP connection ok, sql statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I get this to echo or print out the results of a select statement via php?

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>

<?php

$query="SELECT * FROM mydb.product";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "$result";
echo $result;
?>
```

I've gotten this far now, but it still returns nothing. Does the problem lie within my mysql table?  Or does it fall somewhere else

```
    <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mydb.test;");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
?>

<h1> Im here</h1>
<?php

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>

<h1> Im still here</h1>
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: You need to use a loop. Either a `while` or `foreach` - Do `$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and you'll see the error of your present method.

Comment: You need to fetch the data with `mysql_fetch_array()` or similar, possibly in a loop as @fred suggests. read the reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: As per your edit: *Woah now cowboy!* - You're mixing MySQL APIs, you can't do that. You're connecting with `mysql_` then querying with PDO. Read up on PDO http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Answer (score 0):

You need to look through the results. If there are, say, 3 columns in each row then your code would look something like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    $row_array=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo($row_array[0]." ".$row_array[1]." ".$row_array[2]."<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you'll have to loop through the fetched results:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM mydb.product";
$result=mysql_query($query);

// Add these lines:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  var_dump($row);
  // each item from the row could be used like this:
  // echo $row['field'];
}
```

More information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Please note that mysql_query is depricated, and you should consider switching to mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: should i just abandon the mysql_query if I'm using php > 5.5? And the var dump dumps everything, and even with a echo $row['field'] its a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.  It wouldn't require much to switch your code to mysqli (notice the "i"), or if you like to learn something different, try PDO.

Comment: As for the amount you're echoing, it's because you are basically dumping the whole database table.  Try changing your query to something like $query="SELECT * FROM mydb.product LIMIT 10";